# Same deployment working is working fine in Docker-Desktop, not in AKS

Tags: azure-aks

I'm working with a basic angular application. My image is in **docker hub**. I've applied a **Deployment** and **Load Balancer** service in 2 namespaces, **Docker Desktop** and **AKS**. The code is working just fine in Docker Desktop while in the AKS version is only displaying the NGINX default page.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment  
metadata:
  name: k8sbeginner-frontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: k8sbeginner-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8sbeginner-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8sbeginner-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: k8sbeginner-frontend
        image: namespace/k8sbeginner-frontend:v1
        ports:
         - containerPort: 80
```

this the content of the version I deployed in **Docker-Desktop**. All the angular build files are present.

[image]

However, when it comes to AKS, all I see are the default NGINX files, no angular build files.

[image]

When I run kubectl describe pod [NAME], this is what I get:

[image]

Everything seems to go well. So it's not working in the AKS? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this option **imagePullPolicy: Always**, and it worked.

```
 containers:
      - name: k8sbeginner-frontend
        image: namespace/k8sbeginner-frontend:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
         - containerPort: 80
```